# Spring Batch JpaItemWriter performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, itemwriter

I use spring batch JpaItemWriter to insert db with 11500 records(8 columns for that table), and I thought its performance will be good, but it was not as fast as I expected.
11500 records took about 60 seconds with chunk size 100, then I raise the size to 10000, but it still took about 50 seconds.
Could any one suggest better way to do bulk insert or update by spring batch?

a better way to insert or update large amount of data by spring batch

Comment: Can you try inserting those records into a temp file and load it using native db command to load into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JpaItemWriter` delegates item writing to a JPA `EntityManager`. So the performance of the writer is bound to the performance of the JPA implementation you use. What Spring Batch does is chunking items and then calling either `entityManager.persist` or `entityManager.merge` (depending on the `usePersist` parameter).

That said, raw JDBC inserts usually perform better than JPA, but this depends on the case. You need to try both approaches and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to use jdbcBatchItemWriter, and the time used by this job reduced to about 3 seconds. I will test related update and delete operations again , really appreciate your answer